# What is the default datasource type for mybatis?

Tags: mybatis

I'm a beginner when it comes to mybatis, and I have a question I've been trying to research as well.

If for instance, the `datasource type` tag wasn't declared in any configuration xml, is there like a default type that mybatis uses for this kind of instances? I'm talking the similar case when a `port` is not declared, `8080` will be used.

Is mybatis doing something similar like that?

"Oh it wasn't declared so I'll go with `UNPOOLED` datasource type"

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.5.13 there is no default value for the `type` attribute in the datasource definition.

You can check the [source code](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/builder/xml/XMLConfigBuilder.java#L347):

```
private DataSourceFactory dataSourceElement(XNode context) throws Exception {
    if (context != null) {
      String type = context.getStringAttribute("type");
      Properties props = context.getChildrenAsProperties();
      DataSourceFactory factory = (DataSourceFactory) resolveClass(type).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
      factory.setProperties(props);
      return factory;
    }
    throw new BuilderException("Environment declaration requires a DataSourceFactory.");
  }
```

as you can see `getStringAttribute` is invoked without specifying any default value and then the `type` is used as is which makes it a mandatory field.